# hide buttons in web forms app if being page has two user control refs

Tags: webforms

I am working on a web forms app where one of my user controls is used on multiple pages.  Is there a simple if/else statement that can hide a div if not referenced to a specific page.  For instance, I have a button group that is showing in both page A and B but I only need it to show on page B if that page is active.  Any help  will be appreciated.

Here is the button group I wish to have only shown on one user control:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblQty"  runat="server"  AssociatedControlID="txtQuantity">Quantity</asp:Label>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeQuantity('minus');" id="minus-btn"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"  cssClass="form-control form-control-sm"  runat="server" value="1" min="1" max= ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeQuantity('plus');" id="plus-btn"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                              
                        </div>
```

This is the block that is showing on two different .ascx controls.

Comment: Edit your question with some code sample. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a public property in the ascx control:

```
public string MyPage { get; set; }
```

and in a method (or in a PreRender event) you can use:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   MyButton.Visible =  MyPage == "B";   
}
```

You can set the property from page B.aspx

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc" TagName="MyControl" 
    Src="~/Controls/MyControl.ascx" %>

<cc:MyControl runat="server" Id="MyControlId" MyPage="B" />
```

Comment: I just made an edit to my update with code of the button group.  Please let me know.

Comment: Change your button with `<asp:Button runat="server" ...>`

Comment: do I still need to use the other code you provided or just add a button control?

Comment: You can use my post code but to use `MyButton.Visible`, your `<button ...>` must be an `<asp:Button runat="server" ...>`